# Could not install package 'Microsoft.Owin.Security 2.0.1'

Tags: c#, asp.net

Could not install package 'Microsoft.Owin.Security 2.0.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

what i should i have to now...?

thanks in advance..

Comment: If you are installing last versions of SignalR you will not be able as it has some dependencies that require .Net4.5, but you can still install an old version of SignalR which uses .Net4.0, like 1.1.3 `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -Version 1.1.3`

Answer (score 4):

This means they created a nuget package that only contains assemblies targeted at other framework versions, for example Framework 4.5

If your project needs to stay on Framework 4.0 you can try to use a previous version of the package by using the nuget package manager console and issue the following command:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security -Version X.X.X
```

Where X.X.X is a previous version number.

You can find the version history here :

```
http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security
```

Or you can use Visual Studio 2012/2013 and create a project that targets Framework 4.5, then you will not get this error.